# Very weird NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, classloader

I have a situation where I get a NoClassDefFoundError. Since there is not much information available, and I am 100% positive that the class is there, I made some detailed testing with Eclipse debugger:

1. Start Java Program in Debug mode
2. When it stops (somewhere), I check the classpath of the running thread (in debug mode). The directory of the "missing" class is there, and the .class file is also there.
3. In the Expressions window, I add two expressions:

   a)  new MyClass() --> leads to NoClassDefFoundError

   b) MyClass.class -> shows the Class Definition!?!?
4. I put a breakpoint at the first line of the constructor of MyClass, and it never stops there, so the Constructor is never called... Calling private static final fields on the class works from the debug Window...

How can that be? I also spied the process with VisualVM and I can see the "MyClass" definition. What can cause such an error when the class is there?

I cannot get a small replicatable example of this case, since I have no clue what causes it. The unit tests of the class can instantiate it, this behaviour only happens in an integrated context.

Comment: Share some code where you're getting this error.

Comment: This can occur if there is a failure while initializing the class, typically when we have an exception in static blocks, check all your static blocks

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, that was exactly the cause... There was a call to a Spring Bean in a static initializer...

Comment: @Martin I added it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can occur if there is a failure while initializing the `class`, typically when we have an `exception` in `static blocks` so you should check all your `static blocks` to make sure that none of them throw a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: The annoying part of this problem is that the Stacktrace of the exception in the static block is not always shown... You only see the NoClassDefFoundError... This is a frustrating scenario to analyze...

Comment: Yes I know, it is always hard to find, that is the reason why we need to secure the most we can the code that we execute in a static block

Comment: ...or simply avoid accessing external dependencies in static blocks... :)

Answer (score 2):

I belive that `NoClassDefFoundError` can be due to a linkage problem. When you do:

`MyClass.class`

You are *loading* the class but not initializing it; that means that references used in the initialization do not need to be resolved. On the other hand when you create an instance:

`new MyClass()`

... the class does require initialisation, references need to be resolved, and you can get a failure at that point - which indeed you do. To me, this implies that the class refers to another class which cannot be loaded for some reason, or that initialization of the class is failing (though the latter normally gives `ExceptionInInitializerError` instead).

Comment: Yep, I was suspecting something similar. But how to find out what is missing? Eclipse has no errors in the Workspace, project builds well...

Comment: @Martin catch the error, `getCause()`, print the stack trace of the cause - maybe. :) Good luck.